# Pay raise as per bank salary scale

Tags: salary, raise, employees

I have joined a bank in March 2018. They offered me something around less than 30k USD per annum. Now I have passed my probationary period successfully, I came to know that range for my position is 80k per annum at a minimum, I am reporting to COO and he was on business trip. i talked with CEO and he told me that come after you completed 6 months of your employment if your line manager COO approved will change your salary but cannot give you the range of this position.

What is your advice?

Comment: [What is your question?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/25739)

Comment: Note that you're very unlikely to get a 167%+ raise (although such things do happen).

Comment: To the OP, I don't know if you have international customers. If you do, my first advice for you is to improve your English proficiency. Once your English is improved, you have better chance to get pay raise.

Comment: How do you know it's 80k minimum?

Comment: What country do you work in?  Are you in any way restricted from changing companies?

Comment: Is this 80k the rate for those just out of probation or those with say 10 years experience - the employer may have progression through a salary band based on time served.

Answer (score 6):

From what you say, it sounds like you did a poor job of negotiating salary when you applied for the position, which may have been a factor in why they hired you. Why wouldn't they, if you're willing to work for 40% of what other candidates are willing to work for? You're a dream employee! ;-)

Best way to increase your salary quickly is to excel at what you are doing and also apply for other similar positions. If you're great at what you do, and you tell them you're going to leave because your salary is too low and you've got a better offer, then they will (should) increase it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am reporting to COO and he was on business trip. i talked with CEO
>   and he told me that come after you completed 6 months of your
>   employment if your line manager COO approved will change your salary
>   but cannot give you the range of this position.
>
> What is your advice?

My advice is to wait until the COO returns from his business trip. Then talk with him about getting a raise.

Basically - do what the CEO told you to do.